# HTACCESS redirects with post data

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, post

I added these lines to redirect all URLs to the same URLs with www .

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST [NC]
```

I am providing API to users. users how send http post request to domain.com are successfully getting the proper response however users how sends http requests to www.domain.com are not getting the proper response, i figured that was because the htaccess redirection i cannot read post data from their requests.

How can i redirect any urls without www to with www but keeping the post data?
I am using codeigniter.

Comment: You need to move the last condition up one line.

Comment: didn't work, can you give me the conditions and rules to work in codeigniter ?

Answer (score 1):

Mike Rockett's comment is right, a `RewriteCond` after a `RewriteRule` directive is not a correct way to configure an Apache HTTP Server with an *.htaccess* file..

Anyway, you can try to check this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(HEAD|POST)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If the above code didn't work, then you can just exclude the URLs of the pages that are receiving a POST request like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !post-receiver\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/post-receiver-containing-folder/
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @T4mer Did you try to configure the _.htaccess_ file in the root of your domain with those directives? Did you also try the second option?

Comment: @T4mer Maybe you did not modify the `RewriteCond` directives for the correct URIs..